# does any botnet/malware traffic use ssh or anything else other than TCP/IP?

Tags: malware

if i sniff all traffic leaving my router, if botnet traffic is present will it be IP traffic or does any malware use other protcols such as SSH, FTP, TFTP, etc?? do antivirus software programs routinely perform exit traffic pattern analysis? would it be useful to create a utility that does routinely analyse such traffic and displays it in a user friendly format?

Comment: SSH, FTP, TFTP etc use TCP/IP.

Comment: Do you mean HTTP, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The Internet is a packet switched network, so malware is going to use a packet switched network.  It may use UDP or TCP or possibly one of a couple rare other options, but all the protocols you mentioned use TCP/IP for their transport.  If you are truly sniffing all traffic across the router, then you would see the traffic since the router will report all traffic it is passing through.  If the router doesn't know about it, then the information can't go across the router.

Comment: i am sorry for misstating my question. my only explanation is that i have been used to dealing with relatively uninformed people. Of course ssh, ftp, etc are ip packets. maybe if i narrow the scope of my inquiry. there has recently been considerable discussion on reddit and elsewhere about Intel, and possibly other hardware manufacturers, installing backdoors. in general what would be the pseudocode to write a routine that detects traffic leaving the box (local switch, whatever) as the result of installed software malice, and in particular how to detect traffic from hardware backdoors.

Comment: If the hardware on the router doesn't report it, then there is no way to tell short of building your own device from scratch.  You need a device that will report everything on the line and not pass anything along that it doesn't report.  There is no way around that.